# How to escape '@' (at) symbol when pulling git repository on Linux shell

Tags: linux, git, shell

I'm trying to pull a git repository from command line, specifying username and password inside the command, like this:

```
git pull https://username:password@myrepo.kilnhg.com/.../myRepo.git
```

The problem is that my username is an e-mail, so apparently the character '@' need to be escaped, if not, I receive the message:

```
fatal: repository 'https://username:password@myrepo.kilnhg.com/.../myRepo.git/' not found
```

Someone had the same problem and resolved it?

Comment: I don't think the @symbol is the issue.. looking for ya

Comment: Try and replace it with %40

Comment: @FirebladeDan It's what I thought, but specifying another username (without '@') I get a different error: `fatal: Authentication failed for ...`

Comment: @VonC Works with %40, thanks! Maybe you want to post it as an answer.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Usually, you can try and [**percent encode**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Percent-encoding) your password, replacing `@` with `%40`

```
git pull https://username:<yourPasswordwith%40>@myrepo.kilnhg.com/.../myRepo.git
                                           ^^^
```